# How to upload Excel or CSV to MySQL data base using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have an Excel file containing data(list of Phone numbers), and i want that data from, Excel file to be imported in to my Database table(for example called phonenumber_list) using PHP code? i know how to convert MySQl in to Excel, but can it possible in reverse? Please Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CSV**
If you can convert the Excel file to CSV first, you can use [`mysqlimport`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html) to import CSV.  This is probably the quickest method for getting the data into MySQL.

You can do this from PHP using [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).  This is a sample SQL statement to import `data.csv`:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE phonenumber_list
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

**Excel**
If you cannot use CSV, and need to work with raw Excel files, you will need a PHP library which is capable of reading Excel files.

There are a few available, but I don't know how reliable or how well maintained they are:

[Pear: Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer](http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer/redirected)

[PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

[PHP-ExcelReader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/)

You may also want to look at the alternative approach of using the Excel API, but you'll need Excel installed to do that.  There's a little information about that here:

http://www.sydphp.org/presentations/010606-excel.html

If you use this approach, you will need to write some code that reads and parses the Excel file, and sends it to MySQL row-by-row.  This may work out a lot slower than a bulk CSV import.

Comment: mysqlimport and LOAD DATA INFILE, use only CSV or will it work with EXCEl file too...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make that clear.  `LOAD DATA INFILE` will only work with CSV files.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

First you have to convert the Excel file into CSV format (comma delimited) file.

Then use the following PHP script to insert it in MySQL:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
@mysql_select_db("dbname");

$inputFile=@$_FILES[csv][name];
$ext=end(explode('.',$inputFile));

if($ext=='csv')
{
    $tmpFile=@$_FILES[csv][tmp_name];
    $f = @fopen($tmpFile, 'r');
    $contents = @fread($f, 10000); 
    fclose($f);
    $fileLines = explode("\r\n", $contents); // explode to make sure we are only using the first line.
    $fieldList_header = explode(',', $fileLines[0]);
    $csv_header=array("ID","Name","Address","Email-Id","Contact-No"); // Excel file heading

    $i=0;
    //index keys for each column
    $ID_key=null;
    $Name_key=null;
    $Address_key=null;
    $Email_ID_key=null;
    $Contact_No_key=null;

    foreach($csv_header as $csv)
    {
        //searching index for each value
        if(in_array($csv,$fieldList_header))
        {
            $key=array_search($csv,$fieldList_header);

            if($i==0)
                $ID_key=$key;   
            if($i==1)
                $Name_key=$key;
            if($i==2)
                $address_key=$key;
            if($i==3)
                $Email_ID_key=$key;
            if($i==4)
                $Contact_No_key=$key;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Failed to search : ".$csv." blank space will be inserted.<br>";
        }
        $i++;
    }
    echo "<table border=1px>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo "Id";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo "Name";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo "Address";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo "Email ID";
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
            echo "Contact No";
        echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $j=1;
    for($i=2;$i<count($fileLines)-1;$i++)
    {

        $fieldList_other = explode(',', $fileLines[$i]);
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo $fieldList_other[$ID_key];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo $fieldList_other[$Name_key];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo $fieldList_other[$Address_key];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo $fieldList_other[$Email_ID_key];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo $fieldList_other[$Contact_No_key];
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        $query="insert into Contact (EmployeeName,DateOfJoining,SalaryPerDay,Address,Designation,BalanceLeaves,ContactNumber) values('$fieldList_other[$ID_key]','$fieldList_other[$Name_key]','$fieldList_other[$Address_key]','$fieldList_other[$Email_ID_key]','$fieldList_other[$Contact_No_key]')";

        $result=mysql_query($query);
        if(!$result)
            echo "Record $j failed.<br>";
        else
            echo "Record $j inserted in database.";
        $j++;
    }
    echo "</table>";    
}
?>




<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Import a CSV File with PHP & MySQL</title>
        <script>
            <!--
            function noempty()
            {
            var y=document.forms["form1"]["csv"].value;
            if (y==null || y=="" )
              {
                alert("Please enter the required field");
                return false;
              }

            }
            -->
        </script> 
    </head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
<center>
</br></br>
  Choose your file: <br />
    <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" />
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return noempty()"/>
  </center>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

This script will be helpful to you. Because whatever the order of Excel file columns the respective data is only entered in MySQL.