# mysql data to excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel

here is my code..but excel sheet is unexpected.[here is my excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrO8s.jpg)

```
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        mysql_select_db("personel");

        header( "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel" ); 
        header( "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=TumPersonel.xls" );
        header("CONTENT-TYPE: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 

        if(isset($_POST["aktar"])){
        echo mb_convert_encoding('Personel Adı Soyadı'."\t". 'Firma Adı'."\t".'İstihdamı'."\t".'Fiili Çalıştığı Kuruluş'."\t".'Fiili Ünvanı'."\t". 'Kadrosunun Bulunduğu Kuruluş'."\t". 'Kadro Ünvanı'."\t". 'İşe Başladığı Tarih'."\t".'Sicil No'."\t". 'Mezuniyet'."\t". 'Mezun Olduğu Okul'."\t". 'Mezun Olduğu Bölüm/Branş'."\t".'TC Kimlik No'."\t".'Cinsiyet'."\t".'Doğum Tarihi'."\t".'Doğum Yeri'."\t".'Baba Adı'."\t".'Anne Adı'."\t". 'Medeni Hali'."\t". 'Çocuk Sayısı'."\t". 'Kan Grubu'."\t". 'E-Mail'."\t". 'Telefon'."\t". 'Adres'."\t". 'İlçe'."\t". "\n","windows-1254","utf-8");

        $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM workers ORDER by ID");

        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
            echo mb_convert_encoding( $row['username']. "\t" .$row['firma']. "\t" .$row['istihdam']. "\t" .$row['firm']. "\t" .$row['funvan']. "\t". $row['kkurulus']. "\t" .$row['kunvan']. "\t" .$row['tarih']. "\t" .$row['sicilno']. "\t" .$row['mezun']. "\t" .$row['mezuno']. "\t" .$row['mezunb']. "\t" .$row['tcno']. "\t" .$row['cins']. "\t" .$row['dtarih']. "\t" .$row['dyer']. "\t" .$row['badi']. "\t" .$row['aadi']. "\t" .$row['medeni']. "\t" .$row['csayisi']. "\t" .$row['kgrup']. "\t" .$row['email']. "\t" .$row['tel']. "\t" .$row['adres']. "\t" .$row['ilce']."\n","windows-1254","utf-8");
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're sending the mimetype for an Excel file, and following it with tab-separated values. This won't work. If you want to create an Excel file look at [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), or send comma-separated values.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163559/how-to-upload-excel-or-csv-to-mysql-data-base-using-php

Answer (score 3):

try out with

`$filename = d:/download/excelFileName.xls  //filename with folder path where you want to save excel file`

`$getExcelData = 'SELECT column1, column2, column3 from workers  INTO OUTFILE  "'.$filename.'"  FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"' //mysql query;`

`$getResult = mysql_query($getExcelData _csv); //after execution of this query your excel file will created on d:/dowload folder by name excelFileName.xls`


 its work for me
 refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: i couldn't integrated it to my code..sorry i'm bad on that

Comment: if your problem will not solve then reply i ll try my best

Comment: i have updated my answer, have a look

Comment: thanks for your answer.i'm gonna try then turn back to you

Comment: i have to use isset function for call excel but i couldn't again :((

Comment: mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
   mysql_select_db("personel");

   header( "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel" ); 
   header("CONTENT-TYPE: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 
   if(isset($_POST["aktar"])){
   $filename = "d:/download/personel.xls" 

   $getExcelData = 'SELECT username, firm from workers INTO OUTFILE "'.$filename.'" FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","     OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"' ;
   
   $getResult = mysql_query($getExcelData);
   }

Comment: may be this link will helpfull for you refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to remove this line:

`header("CONTENT-TYPE: text/html; charset=utf-8");`

Comment: It is not relevant here.